# Magento upgrade to EE 1.13.x

Tags: magento-enterprise, upgrade, url-rewrite, ee-1.13

I faced with issue during Magento updating from Magento EE 1.12.0.2 to EE 1.13.x.
After running script `php -f shell/url_migration_to_1_13.php` all of my product URL's were changed from `<product-url>` to `<product-url>-1`. And weird rewrite rules were added for old URL (check the following image)
[image]

Comment: Has Magento answered you yet? There was a URL rewrite bug and a patch for it. (From 1.12)